# On the string-key order of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

All browsers I've tested

```
Object.keys({ a: 'a', c: 'c', b: 'b' })
```

on give

```
["a", "c", "b"]
```

My question is: Are there Javascript implementations that give something else?

My question is **not**: Does the standard guarantee it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are. This is my implementation that does not return the keys in order:

```
Object.keys = obj => {
  const result = [];
  for(let key in obj) result.push(key);
  result.sort(() => Math.random() * 2 - 1);
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Strange answer, though. I would also be interested in knowing are there any *real* engines that don't return keys in order. This answer doesn't really answer this.

Comment: @dfsq I'm still not sure why that is relevant. If you want sorted keys, just do `Object.keys(obj).sort()`

Comment: @JonasW. This isn‘t about sorting but about retaining the original order.

Comment: @john but if the specs make the order unpredictable, why not just make it predictable with `.sort()` ?

Comment: @JonasW. The specs don‘t make it unpredictable. They merely don‘t help making it predictable. You know that there are languages that don‘t even have a spec? Spec‘s are a tool, not a faith. But there‘s a lot of people who take them as one.

Comment: @john depends on the language, and in JS the Specs are the only source of truth :)

Comment: @JonasW. That‘s incorrect. If you find a contradiction between implementation tradition and the spec, you‘ll see what is the source of truth and what is merely superstition.